# Using GPUImageMovieWriter to record video of changing filters on a still image?

Tags: ios, gpuimage

The only documentation I can find for the use of `GPUImageMovieWriter` involves writing from a video source, but I need to take a still image and generate a video by varying the parameters of a `GPUImageFilter` over time.

I've tried chaining `GPUImagePicture -> GPUImageFilter -> GPUImageTextureOutput` and implementing the `newFrameReadyFromTextureOutput:` delegate like so:

```
-(void)newFrameReadyFromTextureOutput:(GPUImageTextureOutput *)callbackTextureOutput {
    NSLog(@"new frame ready delegate method");
    [writer setInputTexture:callbackTextureOutput.texture atIndex:0];
    [writer newFrameReadyAtTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(time, 1) atIndex:0];
    [...]
```

and then adjusting the parameters and calling `-processImage` all over again; this produces an output video of the right length, but the image is garbled. Is there any supported way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the `GPUImageMovieWriter` as a target of any filter.

Comment: Did you actually try this? As far as I can tell, it's not this simple. In `GPUImageMovieWriter.m`, in the method `- (void)newFrameReadyAtTime:(CMTime)frameTime atIndex:(NSInteger)textureIndex`, the documentation states that the input frame will be dropped if the source is an image.